# ReadOnlySpan variant?

Tags: c#

```
public string Get()
{
    string cleaned = Number.Trim().Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty).Replace("_", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace(",", string.Empty);
    return cleaned.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper();
}
```

How could the `.Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace(...` and ToUpper be written using ReadOnlySpan in an efficient way?

```
public string Get()
{
    ReadOnlySpan<char> cleaned = Number.AsSpan().Trim(); // ??? .Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty).Replace("_", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace(",", string.Empty);
    return cleaned.Slice(0, 2); //??? .ToUpper();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Replace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0) API does not provide a way to specify multiple patterns at the same time.

- You can try to use Regex
- Or you can take advantage of the [`Split`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0) and [`Join`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0) API calls

```
char[] toBeRemovedCharacters = new[] { '.', '-', '_', ' ', ',' };
string Get(string number)
{
    var chunks = number.Trim()
       .Split(toBeRemovedCharacters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var cleaned = string.Join("", chunks);
    return cleaned.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper();

}
```